# argument error/wrong number of arguments - I have no idea what's going on here,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, arguments, parameters

I'm trying to use paperclip and update a listing but whenever I do that on the form I receive this error.

ArgumentError in ListingsController#update
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Code is as follows and the line with that is highlighted as being at fault begins with **if @listing.update(listing_params)**

```
     @listing = Listing.new
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
```

This is the application trace

```
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:45:in `block in update'
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:44:in `update'
```

Is there something I'm missing, syntax-wise, or is it something else?  Many thanks.

EDIT:

The code for my listings model (listings.rb) is as follows

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url  => "default.jpg"
end
```

My form  (_form.html.erb) is as follows:

```
<%= form_for @listing, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @listing.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@listing.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this listing from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @listing.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you post your listing_params method?

Comment: def listing_params
            params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :description,  :price, :image)
        end  'code'

Comment: @user3716559, edit your question by adding the model description and the form your using to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating your listing. You need to remove

> @listing = Listing.new

By writing this you are initialising a listing. It's an update method hence you need to find your listing not initialise a new listing so try

```
@listing = Listing.find(params[:id]) #this will find your listing with id
respond_to do |format|
  if @listing.update(listing_params) #this will update the listing which you find above
    format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    #code
  end
end
```

Comment: I did change this but it brings out a 'wrong number of arguments' error for the following line:    'if @listing.update(listing_params) # the refer to it and update it'

Comment: @user3716559 Now how does your update method looks like?

Comment: `def update
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id]) #find item you want to update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params) # the refer to it and update it
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end `

Comment: sorry it looks unattractive here, it's the same, except where you've put #code, I have some actions for allow for editing or listing errors.

Comment: @user3716559 This type of error usually comes when there is a mis match in the number of arguments are passed. Can you try using update_attributes(listing_params).

Comment: Would that be like `@listing.update_attributes(listing_params)` instead of `@listing.update(listing_params)` ?

Comment: @user3716559 yeah and add :id to the listing_params too

Comment: @user3716559 no problem! Thanks for accepting! Was it the id not being passed in the listing_params which was causing the error because update_attribute is just an alias method to update

Comment: I assume so, adding that allowed it go through :)

Comment: @user3716559 i had a doubt about the id thing but i wasn't sure, anyways glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You update controller method should look like this ;

```
def update
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id]) #find item you want to update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params) # the refer to it and update it
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
    end
  end
```

Comment: the line beginning with: if @listing' is still being highlighted as producing the 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: @user3716559, add code for yor form and Listing Model to better understand the information your passing during the update.

Comment: @Acacia He is using rails4, rails4 uses strong parameters